# select in Nhibernate by HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have some mapping:

```
<class entity-name="Person" table="table1">
<id column="Id" type="long" name="Id"/>
<set name="Address">
<key column="Person_id"/>
<one-to-many class="Address"/>
</set>
<property column="Id" name="Id" type="long"/>
<property column="Last_Name" name="LastName" type="string"/>
<property column="First_Name" name="FirstName" type="string"/>
<property column="Education" name="Education" type="string"/>   
</class>

<class entity-name="Address" table="table2">
<id column="Id" type="long" name="Id"/>
<property column="Id" name="Id" type="long"/>
<property column="City" name="City" type="long"/>
<property column="Street" name="Street" type="string"/>
<property column="number" name="number" type="string"/>
</class>
```

It's my HQL query
       hbm= "from person p join fetch p.Address WHERE p.id in (:ids)"

but now I get select * from both tables(Address and Person)
I need HQL that retern LastName,FirstName of person and collection of Addresses that contains City , Street

I haw I add conditions on Address fields??

Comment: Any ideas?? may be it's impossible??

Answer (score 0):

Add Select p to only return Person.
Add an alias to Address so that you can use it in the where clause (conditions).

```
select p from person p join fetch p.Address ad WHERE p.id in (:ids) and a.City = :city
```

Comment: It's return all fields of Person . And I need projection on fields of Person and Projection on fields of Address. I other words part of person column and part of address column .

Answer (score 0):

What about this query?

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.City, a.Street from Person p inner join p.Addresses a WHERE p.Id in (:id) and a.City=:city
```

The result collection contains object arrays then:

```
var resultList = query.List();
foreach (object[] result in resultList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Person.FirstName = {0}", result[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Person.LastName = {0}", result[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Address.City = {0}", result[2]);
    Console.WriteLine("Address.Street = {0}", result[3]);
}
```

Comment: But if one person have 50 addresses . This query return 50 lines. And every line contain FirstName , LastName, City and Street .
And need ONE line with FirstName , LastName and collections of City and Street with size 50

Comment: Yes, it is how inner join works. IMO this duplication is not a problem even when a person has 1000 addresses. What will you do in case when two persons are found? You have 2 result sets: 2 rows with FirstName and LastName in the first result set and 50 rows with City and Street in the second result set. How will you pair off rows from these two result sets? Or you don't need to?